# How are corbaloc: URLs load balanced?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, websphere, corba

I'm using JBoss EAP 5.1 and am connecting to remote EJBs, the java.naming.provider.url is set to:

```
corbaloc::server1:port,server2:port,server3:port,server4:port
```

How is this getting load balanced?  It's not always going in first to last order is it? is it randomized some how?

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on who provides the `corbaloc:` JNDI URL provider (there isn't one in JDK at least up to 1.6), but you're begging the question by describing it as 'load balancing'. It would be more accurate to describe it as 'failover'.

Answer (score 1):

In a clustered Websphere environment you can have many multiple name servers to talk with in the form you describe. 
About your question, [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rnam_example_prop2.html) it mentions that:

> You can specify the bootstrap addresses for all servers in the cluster in the URL. The operation succeeds if at least one of the servers is running, eliminating a single point of failure. **There is no guarantee of any particular order in which the address list will be processed.** For example, the second bootstrap address may be used to obtain the initial context **even though the server at the first bootstrap address in the list is available**.